# How to synchronize Custom resource when its specification is updated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

In a Kubernetes operator based on operator-sdk, do you know how to write code to synchronize CR resource when CR specification is updated with `kubectl apply`? Could you please provide some code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing it a go-lang based operator is pretty complex, and I would recommand studying the kubebuilder documentation and example in order to achieve that: https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/controller-implementation.html#implementing-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly up to how you deploy things. The default skeleton gives you a Kustomize-based deployment structure so `kustomize build config/default | kubectl apply -f`. This is also wrapped up for you behind `make deploy`. There is also `make install` for just installing the generated CRD files.

Comment: Thanks!, but I'd like to get some `go` code sample implementing the logic to synchronize the resource and its yaml specification in the controller reconciliation loop.

Comment: Oh you mean in the operator itself? That's more complicated than I can fit in a SO answer. Come ask in Slack (channel #kubernetes-operators) and I or someone else can give you some pointers. Server side apply is still evolving rapidly so it also depends on which versions you need to support.